# how to disable hard drives in UEFI bios?

Tags: motherboard, bios, uefi

sometimes I need to disconnect a hard drive.  I have to open my computer and unplug the sata power cable.

I am wondering if its possible to disable the hard drive in UEFI bios.

I am using asus p8p67 pro.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: i have dual boot, mac and windows 7, should have nothing to do with what OS i use.

Comment: my question has nothing to do with OS. i want to know if its possible to disable Hard drives in UEFI bios,  I dont want to unmount a drive in Mac OSX.

Comment: You cannot "unmount" a drive while in UEFI Bios.  You can only unmount the drive after your in the operating system.

Comment: Good old BIOS has the option to just select 'none' instead of a detected hard drive. 
If there is such a possibility in UEFI, it really is up to the manufacturer (such an option is actually offered).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly how it is done in terms of editing the UEFI or the EFI files, etc, but it is definitely possible because there is a button to do it in the program called EasyUEFI by Hasleo. I disabled my hard drive using it and it was a little difficult to get it back, but I succeeded. Basically I disabled Secure Boot, then got into the EFI mode where I scrolled down to bootmgrfw.efi and launched Windows from there. Then I used EasyUEFI to re-enable my hard drive.